# Call a function in a sibling component

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component with two child components.

When a button is clicked in one of the child components, I need to call a function in the other child function.

I have tried a number of methods but cannot get it to call correctly.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Is using a `ref` the correct approach here?

Comment: better use redux...

Comment: @sathishkumar you don't need redux, you could simply use a flowing state from parent to children to trigger the functions

Comment: @Sterling Archer please read the question clearly? this is not the question parent to child communication...

Comment: @sathishkumar please understand the react lifecycle before assuming miscommunication. It's very easy for a child component to call a function to set a state in the parent, which will be communicated naturally down to the *other* child component which can use that state as a property to trigger a function call. It's a common practice. You can use redux for it as well, but please don't assume I didn't read something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Callbacks` for this problem. `Redux is for complex data-flow applications`.
This is the working solution.

```js
//ChildOne Component
class ChildOne extends React.Component {
  clickHandler = () => {
    this.props.callbackHandler();
  };
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click ChildOne</button>;
  }
}
//ChildTwo Component
class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    btnClicked: false
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.btnClicked) this.setState({ btnClicked: true });
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.btnClicked !== prevState.btnClicked) {
      return { btnClicked: nextProps.btnClicked };
    } else return null;
  }
  ChildTwoFunc = () => {
    alert("ChildTwo function is invoked");
  };
  render() {
    if (this.state.btnClicked) this.ChildTwoFunc();
    return <div>{this.state.btnClicked}</div>;
  }
}
//Parent Component
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    btnClicked: false
  };
  callbackHandler = () => {
    //console.log("123");
    this.setState({ btnClicked: true });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildOne callbackHandler={this.callbackHandler} />
        <ChildTwo btnClicked={this.state.btnClicked} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked without the `getDerivedStateFromProps` function. What is the purpose of the `getDerivedStateFromProps` in this case?